# Inserting NULL values into mdf table in Windows Forms

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here, in the debugger when I set breakpoints the strings all have string values in them, but when it comes time to insert them into the table, nothing gets put in.

the table is defined as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMissEvents] (
[EventID]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[EventTime]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[MIS_Event_Action] VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
[Bogey_Type]       VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventID] ASC)
```

);

my code:

```
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        string MISaction = text1.Text;
        string BogeyType = text2.Text;

        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString =
                @"data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\MissileEvents.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText =
                "INSERT into tblMissEvents (EventTime, MIS_Event_Action, Bogey_Type) Values (@date, @MISaction, @BogeyType)";  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MISaction", MISaction);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BogeyType", BogeyType);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
```

Any thoughts?? I don't get an exception, just no entry into my table.

edit for Arshad:

```
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =
            @"data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\MissileEvents.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText =
            "INSERT into tblMissEvents (MIS_Event_Action, Bogey_Type) Values (@date, @MISaction, @BogeyType)";  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MISaction", MISaction);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BogeyType", BogeyType);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

UPDATE:: The code was fine, it was making a copy of the DB in my bin\Debug directory and thats where all the data was going. Probably something with my connection string setup. Thanks all!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to store a date value in a text column. Don't do that that.

Comment: but shouldnt it at least store my other values?

Comment: is there any triggers in this table?

Comment: what is a trigger exactly?

Comment: Try setting the command's connection before setting the command's text and parameters

Comment: nope still not inserting

Comment: A trigger is a sql block structure which is fired when a DML statements like Insert, Delete, Update is executed on a database table. A trigger is triggered automatically when an associated DML statement is executed.

You can check the triggers : expand the table > Expand Triggers

Comment: Oh okay, no there are no triggers involved here. I even tried replacing the insert values with 'test' 'test1' and 'test2' and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can pass null value also as :

```
 cmd.CommandText =
            "INSERT into tblMissEvents (EventTime, MIS_Event_Action, Bogey_Type)
                                Values (@eventTime, @MISaction, @BogeyType)";  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventTime", DBNull.Value);          
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MISaction", MISaction);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BogeyType", BogeyType);
```

**Update 1**

```
cmd.CommandText =
        "INSERT into tblMissEvents (EventTime,MIS_Event_Action, Bogey_Type) 
                                Values 
                                   (@date, @MISaction, @BogeyType)";
```

**Update 2**

```
int RowUpdated=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Number of row updated"+RowUpdated);
```

Comment: Still confused, I'm not trying to pass a null value? I just allowed nulls for the fields to see if i could get anything to insert into the table

Comment: update your `cmd.CommandText` as  i have written in first example

Comment: I get an exception because there are fewer columns being inserted than my table?

Comment: Error is because you are passing less parameter, share your updated code

Comment: i posted it, but thats what you said to do, right? your updated sql string is the same as mine but missing one column

Comment: Im really confused man. That is the exact same code as i originally posted?

Comment: no, i missed one column in earlier answer, i was typing mistake

Comment: If you look at my original post, that is the exact same line I have in there. What is different from yours to mine?

Comment: have you checked for entry in the table by refreshing it

Comment: yes I have. For whatever reason its just not inserting any records and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Just to confirm. I tried to test your code exactly as it is and it works fine. I was able to see the records that you add on the table tblMissEvents. I just wonder what is Text1.text? is that the textbox? And do you have other database than this in you local PC and does it work?

Comment: text1.text is just a textbox that Im taking the string value from. As far as local DBs i dont have any other ones. Did I set this up wrong??

Comment: Have you tried checking your connection string? What's the name of your database by the way?

Comment: in the debugger the connection string says its connected, the db is called MissileEvents.mdf

Comment: Just for a try, kindly change your connection string with a different approach like "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MissileEvents;Integrated Security=SSPI;" and see if it works and records could be added in your table. And by the way I think you should follows @Arshad testing suggestion showing the Row Updated.

Comment: UPDATE:: The code was fine, it was making a copy of the DB in my bin\Debug directory and thats where all the data was going. Probably something with my connection string setup. Thanks all!